# What does "WebapiError" mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spotify

I'm working on Spotify Web App that just retrieves KD Rusha Top Albums trying to used Client ID, Artist ID to fetch only KD Rusha top album releases on his  Spotify. I'm using an npm package called [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-node).

Error Message[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node';
require('dotenv').config();

// My Steps: //
// GO TO SPOTIFY AND GETTING KD RUSHA TOP ABLUMS lIMIT TO 9 SONGS
// WHEN YOU CLICK ON TOP OF THE ABLUMS A PLAY BUTTON ICON WILL SHOW TO INDICATE THAT YOU CAN PLAY 30 SECONDS OF SONG

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId : 'here where client id',
  clientSecret : 'here where client secret',
  redirectUri : 'http://www.localhost.com/callback'
});

export default class SpotifyComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.fetchData();
    }, 3000)
  }

 fetchData() {//Its Fetch Artist Albums The Spotify Date
   spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums('5JLWikpo5DFPqvIRi43v5y', {limit: 9})
     .then(function(data) {
       return data.body.albums.map(function(a) { return a.id; });
     })
     .then(function(albums) {
       return spotifyApi.getAlbums(albums);
     }).then(function(data) {
       console.log(data.body);
   });
 }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='spoify-container'>
        <img src="{image.albums}" alt="kdrusha-albums" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statusCode you're getting back is `401 Unauthorized` which means there's a problem with the credentials. Make sure you're initializing `clientId` and `clientSecret` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a 401 unauthorized error. Something must be wrong with the way your authenticating with the API. According to Spotify's docs: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#response-status-codes

401 Unauthorized - The request requires user authentication or, if the request included authorization credentials, authorization has been refused for those credentials.

Check your credentials.